# BigQuery standard SQL table wildcards with date columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting an error when using a date column in the BigQuery web UI, with a query in standard SQL, when using table wildcards.

This works:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  sale_item,
  date_of_sale
FROM `my-project.past_sales.sales_20170601`
limit 100
```

This does not:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  sale_item,
  date_of_sale
FROM `my-project.past_sales.sales_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20170530" AND "20170601"
limit 100
```

The column `date_of_sale` is type `DATE`, while `sale_item` is type `STRING`.  The error is: `Error: Invalid adaptation for field: date_of_sale (message Msg_0_CLOUD_QUERY_TABLE). Cannot change from TYPE_STRING to int32`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that `date_of_sale` is a `DATE` in one table and a `STRING` in another. You can find the culprit by taking a union instead:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `my-project.past_sales.sales_20170530` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `my-project.past_sales.sales_20170531` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `my-project.past_sales.sales_20170601`;
```

You don't actually need to run the query; the validator in the UI will indicate where the mismatched column type is.

To fix the error, you can either regenerate the data for the problematic day, applying a cast, or you can run a query with a union instead where you add an explicit cast. For example, supposing that the table for `20170531` has the column as a `STRING`, you could do:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  sale_item,
  date_of_sale
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM `my-project.past_sales.sales_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20170530" AND "20170601" AND
    _TABLE_SUFFIX != 20170531
) UNION ALL
SELECT * REPLACE(CAST(date_of_sale AS DATE) AS date_of_sale)
FROM `my-project.past_sales.sales_20170531`
LIMIT 100;
```